# Python to PHP? For twitter scraper (Scweet)

Tags: python, php, web-scraping, twitter

I found a Twitter scraper library on Github.

(Scweet: https://github.com/Altimis/Scweet)

and I want to use it in the PHP programming language (especially for scraping some tweets using dates)

How can I do that while this library uses python language?

Sorry for my bad English.

Thank you.

Comment: you cant. Try to call the python script in php, or something like that, because python is perfect for web scrapping, but php dont have many facilities and plugins for this.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. I would suggest either going with Python or PHP, and not one within the other. There is another post here on SO where a guy have made a small collection of web scraping tools per programming language, you could take a look at that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2861/options-for-html-scraping

Comment: Rewriting a project from one language to another language is a big undertaking and requires being fluent in both languages. It's one of those "if you have to ask how to do it, you're really nowhere near ready for it" projects. Find a library that does what you need for the language you're using, instead of looking at other language solutions.